# How to Extend NURBS Curve

Tags: linear-algebra, nurbs

Having this represetation of a NURBS curve:

[image: NURB curve mathematical notion]

where `Bi` is all the control points, `t` a parameter defining a point  along the curve and `Ni,k(t)` is the Basis function defined as:

[image: Basis Function]

where `k` is the order of the curve and `Xi` is the conventional notation for the ith knot in the knot vector.

What formula can be used to extend the curve only by modifying position of existing control points while mantaining the existent shape (only extended)?